# How to find the best parameters which maximizes a function?

Tags: r, optimization

I have a function which takes 8 parameters, 5 (`a,b,c,d,e`) of which are constants while the other three (`u1, u2, u3`) are to be found out.

```
a <- 10.1
b <- 2.45
c <- 0.35
d <- 2
e <- 3.5
out <- function(a,b,c,d,e,u1,u2,u3){
temp <- 2*a*b^2 + (u1*u2/d) - c*e^2 + u3*e
return(temp)}
```

I need to find the values of `u1, u2` and `u3` from pre-defined distributions which maximizes the value of `temp`
The distributions are:

```
u1 <- rnorm(100,2,1)
u2 <- rnorm(100, 1, 1.96)
u3 <- rnorm(100, 1, 2.48)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the hypothetical maximum? Or do you want the actual maximum for a specific set of observed values? Maybe checkout the `optim()` function. Maybe checkout this guide: https://www.r-bloggers.com/choosing-which-method-to-use-for-optimizing-functions/

Comment: What is z?  You do not define that.

Comment: It is not clear why you assign distributions to `u1`, `u2`, `u3`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a good way in R to find the exact values of `u1`, `u2`, and `u3` that would maximize your `temp` equation, but for the case you've set up above (based on random samples from the three distributions), you could do the following:

```
a <- 10.1
b <- 2.45
c <- 0.35
d <- 2
e <- 3.5
out <- function(a,b,c,d,e,u1,u2,u3){
temp <- 2*a*b^2 + (u1*u2/d) - c*e^2 + u3*e
return(temp)}

u1 <- rnorm(100,2,1)
u2 <- rnorm(100, 1, 1.96)
u3 <- rnorm(100, 1, 2.48)

res <- out(a,b,c,d,e,u1,u2,u3)
i <- which(res == max(res), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

This just evaluates `temp` for each of the 100 random values for `u1`, `u2`, and `u3`, and finds which draws give the max value of `temp`:

```
> u1[i]
[1] 1.361594
> u2[i]
[1] 2.868618
> u3[i]
[1] 5.958975
```

For greater accuracy, you could increase the sample size to 1,000, 10,000, etc.

Comment: But this computes res only 100 times and finds the best row from u1,u2 and u3. There could be values of u1, u2 and u3 which maximizes the function from different rows.